# What is the proper way to check if msg.sender is the contract owner?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I'm trying to make a function that returns true if msg.sender is the owner.

This is my function;

```
function isAdmin() public view  returns (bool){
   require(admin == msg.sender);
   
    return true;
    
}
```

admin was given the value of msg.sender in the constructor.

Whenever I call this function it revert. From truffle or my app

truffle;

```
x = await contract.deployed()
x.isAdmin()
```

It revert!

My app;

```
await exchange.methods.isAdmin.call()
```

Also revert.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `call` will default to using `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` as `msg.sender`, which is why this is reverting. That address is indeed not `owner`, so a revert is what you would expect. You can do `call` though and specific the msg.sender by doing `await exchange.methods.isAdmin().call({from:addressYouWantToUse})` and replace the placeholder with the owner address

Comment: And how do I read the result from the response? i was expecting just true but i receive a lot back. An object.

Comment: exchange.methods.isAdmin().call({from:addressYouWantToUse}) will return the value returned from the function